# Express keeps getting request.body as undefined JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

I am making an Ajax request that looks like this:

```
 $.ajax({
        url: '/gen',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify({'one': 1, 'two':2}),
        success: function(data) {console.log(this)}
    });
```

and my express portion looks like this:

```
 var express = require('express');
 var app = express();
 var router = express.Router(); 

 app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));

 router.post('/gen', function(req, res) {
     console.log(req.body);
 });
```

this always outputs `undefined` in the console.

How can I change this around to make the req.body, or any part of the req, contain the information I am trying to send over to the express portion of the code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use the body parser.

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

See:

- https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser

You may also need to add:

```
contentType: 'application/json',
```

in your `.ajax()` options.

Comment: you literally helped me with a problem that took me 8 hours. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

To use use `req.body` you have to use the `bodyParser` middleware, import it like this:

```
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.json());

router.post('/gen', function(req, res) {
     console.log(req.body);
 });
```