# Node js request parameter value not parse

Tags: jquery, node.js, cordova

I create node.js server and parse jquery request.

jquery request:

```
 $.post("http://localhost:3000/usertoken/",
        {
          "token": "1212555",
        },
        function(data,status){


 alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
        });
```

Node server

```
var express = require('express');
var sub_server = require('./sub_server.js'); 
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

var app = express();
app.listen(3000);
app.use(express.static('www'))
// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())


app.get('/:id', function(req, res){
    console.log("request:",req.params.id);
    res.send('The id you specified is ' + req.params.id);
});

var firebase_token;
// Post method
app.post('/usertoken', function(req, res){

    var token1 = req.body.token;;
    console.log("req parameter:",token1);

    res.end( JSON.stringify("hemant"));

});
```

I am getting below message.
**req parameter: undefined**

Help me to get post value.

Thank you.

Comment: You can get some good information from this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295782/how-do-you-extract-post-data-in-node-js

Comment: Are you getting any value when you console `req.body` ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use body-parser:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
```

And use:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

if you use JSON body in requests, or this:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

if you use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` - in both cases make sure you send the right MIME type in the request.

See the docs: https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser

For more info see these answers:

- [Express keeps getting request.body as undefined JSON object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41396551/express-keeps-getting-request-body-as-undefined-json-object/41396648#41396648)
- [At server side, Req.body received as { }](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42578660/at-server-side-req-body-received-as/42578884#42578884)
- [req.body is undefined mean app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40790647/req-body-is-undefined-mean-app/40791161#40791161)
- [Write JSON data from front-end to back-end in nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41431426/write-json-data-from-front-end-to-back-end-in-nodejs/41431526#41431526)

Comment: I added serve.js file. Please check it. Getting same error.

Answer (score 0):

While your server should work correctly, your client does not.

You are missing the `contentType` option on the `$.post` call. As you can only specify this parameter if you hand over everything within an object, change the call to the following code to make sure that you not only send JSON data, but that you also set the `content-type` header accordingly:

```
$.post({
  url: "http://localhost:3000/usertoken/",
  data: {
    "token": "1212555",
  },
  contentType: "application/json",
  success: function (data, status) {
    // ...
  }
});
```

The `body-parser` middleware only becomes active if the `content-type` header points out that you are sending JSON data.